setInterval with an ajax request is auto closing DateTimePicker
I have this code below:
setInterval(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ route('logout_checker')}}",
                    type: "GET",
                    success: function(data){
                        if( data == 0 ){
                            location.reload();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }, 1000);

My problem is that it will auto-close the datetime picker (https://nehakadam.github.io/DateTimePicker/)
the picker will pop up and then close so you can't select anything.
is there a better way of handling the ajax request since I'm using that to check if there is still an active session and if there's none it will reload the page so it will go to the login page.
If I remove the ajax request the datetime picker works normally. it's only when the ajax request is present inside the setInterval that the problem occurs.

location.reload(); will ... reload the page.  The datetime picker isn't "closing", it's being completely destroyed with the page and recreated.   Remove location.reload() to confirm that's the problem, not the $.ajax.  Double check the return value / the value of data

@fdomn-m The thing is it's not getting inside the location.reload since it doesn't satisfy the if statement. Also, the page is not reloading

Then there's clearly something else causing the datetimepicker to close that's not included in the question.  Or it's a very strange plugin that closes on all ajax requests...which seems unlikely.  Please provide a complete snippet that demonstrates the issue - see [mvce]

@fdomn-m I was able to fix it using fetch instead of ajax. not sure why that works but it does

jQuery does have some additional events, see https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/ - perhaps there's something in one of those?

those upvoting your comment clearly didn't read the question properly. otherwise, they would've known that the location.reload is inside an if statement. and I would know if the page reloaded because that would be pretty obvious lol

You'd be surprised how often people ask questions here without realising the page is being reloaded (normally a button that is defaulting to submit).  Equally that the response (data in your case) is not actually what they expect yet they expect it to just work.   I would say you "clearly" didn't read the comment as it's not just about .reload.   Without any context, these are safe initial assumptions.  You can feel proud they don't happen to apply to you.

found the fix. I changed from using ajax to fetch.
I'm still not sure why or how this works though but it does. so if anyone can enlighten me about it. it will be highly appreciated.
setInterval(function(){
        fetch("{{ route('logout_checker') }}")
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
                if( data == '0' || data == '' ){
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
    }, 1000);


This isn't a fix in itself, it's just avoiding the mistake you must have made in your jQuery implementation.

all i know is ajax doesn't work with that datetime picker for some reason, and fetch does. so that is a fix in itself. and why should i push on using something that doesn't work and not look for an alternative?
